# Problems on display of video on server in cakephp

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, video

I am using CakePHP and try to display a video on the server but, there was an error like as 'Mime type not found'.

After searching I get the info about ht access problem. So, how can I set the ht access in the CakePHP with video.

I have to add the following lines in to the ht access:-

AddType video/ogg .ogv .ogg

AddType video/webm .webm

AddType video/mp4 .mp4

How to add this into ht access??

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` is a configuration file for Apache webserver that is placed in the root folder of your web project.

[here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ultimate-htaccess-file-sample.html) is an example of how you can edit the content of `.htaccess` file including `AddType`